# How to watch multiple tabs using onEdit function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I came across this script that **moves rows from one tab to another tab depending on the values from a specific column**. It's working perfectly but this can only work on a single tab. Is it possible for this script to run on multiple tabs and move records to a specific tab only?

For example, here is the list of tabs to be watched:

- AAA
- BBB
- CCC
- DDD
- EEE
- etc...

When the value in Column N (contains `=IF formula` that determines the value depending on the condition set) is changed to `Completed`, the script will automatically copy the row to the *DONE* sheet and then delete the row.

I am not sure if `onEdit()` will work.

Note: All of the tabs are identical.

Here is the script I found here in the forum:

```js
function onEdit() {

  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetNameToWatch = ss.getSheetByName("Current")
  var columnNumberToWatch = 8;
  var valueToWatch = "DONE";
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "OLD";

  //var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//this has already been declared
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

  if (sheet.getName() == "Current" && range.getColumn() == 8 && range
  .getValue() == "DONE") {
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("OLD");
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);

    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(
      targetRange);
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
  }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. `onEdit` is triggered when any sheet (tab) is edited. Please show what you tried to adapt the script to your needs.

Comment: I am actually using the script now that whole script except it only works on a single tab. How should I modify the script so that it will work on all my tabs except for the DONE tab?

Comment: Remove `sheet.getName() == "Current" && `

Comment: Also, I forgot to tell you that the watched column has a formula that automatically change to "Completed" when certain conditions are met. I am not sure if onEdit() is the correct function.

Comment: Please edit the question to add to it all the relevant details.

Comment: Scripts are not tied to sheets,they’re tied to projects.

Answer (score 0):

I get that you want to move some rows from different sheets if they meet a criteria, and you need it every time that the spreadsheet is modified. If my comprehension of your question is correct, then you can easily modify the code to put the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) into action by capturing the modified sheet with [`Range.getSheet()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getsheet). At that point you already have a variable with the sheet, so the code can proceed to search for the `Completed` keyword and copy the row to the *DONE* sheet if necessary.